# Prove that $\forall z \in \Bbb C, \exists x \in \Bbb Z[j], |z-x|\leq \frac{\sqrt3}{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, euclidean-domain

Need help proving that $\forall z \in \Bbb C, \exists x \in \Bbb Z[j], |z-x|\leq \frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ \
where $\Bbb Z[j]=\{a+jb / a,b \in \Bbb Z\}$ and $j=e^{\frac{i2\pi}{3}}$.

I thought of using the fact that $(1,j)$ is a basis of $\Bbb C$ and then trying the floor of the coordinates of $z$ but no luck.

Comment: This is the kind of exercise that is easier to understand when you visualize it. Try drawing $\mathbb C$ as a plane and the lattice ${\mathbb Z}[j]$ in it.

Comment: Sounds like a good leed, should have thought about it I'll give it a try thank u